# How to copy N number of cells from array 1 to array 2 , and receive a return value for erro ?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have two arrays in C , and I want to copy N cells of array1 into array2 .

Furthermore , I want to receive the exact number of copied cells .

The function `strncpy` is not good enough for that , since it doesn't have a return value (or it does , but not the one that I'm looking for) .

Any suggestions would be welcomed

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) Also, if you want to copy cells from one array to another, you'll need to specify the length of the arrays. What is your desired function signature for this?

Comment: @Zeta: strncpy , but it didn't help much .I had to check with `strlen` afterwards ...

Comment: Again, the function signature is important. Do you want to have something like `f(double * a1, unsigned size1, double *a2, unsigned size2, unsigned cells)`? Or do you really want to copy a string, like `f(char * str1, char * str2, unsigned cells)`?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `strncpy`? This is for strings and not for arbitrary arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
size_t copy_n(T * dst, T const * src, size_t n)
{
    // method 1
    while (n--) { *dst++ = *src++; }

    // === OR ===

    // method 2
    memcpy(dst, src, n * sizeof(T));

    return n;
}
```

Usage:

```
T a[10];
T b[25];

copy_n(b + 5, a + 2, 7);  // copies a[2]...a[8] into b[5]...b[11]
```

This works only for a fixed, assignable type `T`. If you want a generic function, pass a size argument and use `memcpy` on the entire range:

```
size_t generic_copy_n(void * dst, void const * src, size_t size, size_t n)
{
    memcpy(dst, src, n * size);
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/)

```
memcpy(Array2,Array1,sizeof(*Array1)*N);
```

This will copy without issue and you dont have to care about how many, because once told up it will finish it task anyhow except for failure where you automatically get pop up "Access Violation".

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to achieve the same effect as `strncopy` but also want to know how many bytes have been copied. This can be done with the following code:

```
size_t special_strncopy(char * dest, const char * src, size_t count){
    const size_t original = count--;
    if(count != 0){
        while(*src && count--){
           *dest++ = *src++;
        }
    }
    *dest = '\0'; /* set null-termination symbol */
    return original - count;
}
```

Note `count == 0` will result in undefined behavior, since it includes the 0 symbol.